# Table to Table iterator - Include all fields (different fields for shapefiles)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, csv

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 and trying to convert a number of shapefiles into a CSV document.

[image: My current model]

Some shapefiles have different column names and the Table to Table tool reads in the first columns within the first shapefile and then applies those names to every shapefile, therefore missing some columns.

For example, shp 1 has columns `A B C D`, so the tool specifies to convert each column, but the next shp 2 has columns `A B C D E F`. The tool only prints about `A B C D`, leaving out `E F` from the shp 2.

I would like the tool to convert each column for every shapefile, not just the columns from the first shapefile being read in.

Comment: Are you using any SQL expressions or custom field mapping in the Table to Table tool?

Comment: I'm just leaving the defaults in terms of SQL and field mapping. Whatever the tool populates it with, I leave that in there.

Comment: Are you open to arcpy solutions? This seems ripe for just a bit of coding.

Comment: Very open to ArcPy solutions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue, as you described, is that with a ModelBuilder iterator, the later tools in the workflow have their parameters set by the output from the first loop of the iterator. In a `for` loop in arcpy, each iteration should be independent. So...

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

inFld = ""
arcpy.env.workspace = inFld
outFld = ""

shps = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for shp in shps:
    outName = shp[:-4] #strip .shp from the end of the shapefile tname
    arcpy.TableToTable_conversion (shp, outFld, outName + '.csv')
```

Table to Table also has the options to populate the Field Map of the output table. In the case that the above does not work, you could read the FieldMap from each `shp` and then use that FieldMap in TableToTable.

Comment: This works great thanks! Is there a way to add a wildcard operator and a recursive option to work through subfolders?

Comment: `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()` will take wildcards ([ArcGIS help page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfeatureclasses.htm)), and you could try use os.walk to recursively work through subfolders. Here's another SE page that may help with the latter [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174301/using-arcpy-to-identify-shapefiles-instead-of-os-walk-via-shp-file-extension)

Answer (score 1):

Just insert the "Copy Rows" in between the iteration and the "Table to Table" tool, and make sure to set the Field Map as an empty variable like in this picture:

[image]